# Disable submit button if input field is blank or user enter empty spaces

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, disable

I want to disable my submit button if the user enters empty spaces in the input field. I don't want an empty input field with just spaces showing submit button enabled.

```js
$("#edit-title-input").on("keyup", stateHandle);

function stateHandle(e) {
  // console.log({a:$("#title").text(),b:e.target.value});
  if ($("#title").text() == e.target.value || input.value.length == 0) {
    $('#edit-submit').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#edit-submit').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="edit-title-input"><br>
<button id="edit-submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I would simply use regex. First, get the value of the input as a string. then use regex to remove all spaces and then check if the length is still 0;

Comment: can you share some code for that?

Comment: Or use `trim()`. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### trim() your strings

You can call `trim()` on a string to remove empty space before and after.

See snippet with the modified code:

```js
$("#edit-title-input").on("keyup", stateHandle);

function stateHandle(e) {
  console.log('input value vs. input value.trim()', '"' + e.target.value + '"', '"' + e.target.value.trim() + '"');
  if ($("#title").text() == e.target.value || e.target.value.trim().length == 0) {
    $('#edit-submit').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#edit-submit').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="edit-title-input"><br>
<button id="edit-submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#input1").on("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0 ) {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input1"><br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use regex to remove spaces. then check if the value of that string is still 0 or not. By default you should disable the button. `disabled` is an empty attribute that has no value. So switching it from true to false has no effect as the attribute is still present.

```js
$('#edit-title-input').on('keyup', stateHandle);

function stateHandle(e) {
  var text = $('#edit-title-input').val();
  var regex = text.replace(/ /g,'');
  if (regex.length == 0) {
    $('#edit-submit').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#edit-submit').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="edit-title-input"><br>
<button id="edit-submit" disabled>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all disable the button by default to prevent showing button as able to click on first visit at page
`<button id="edit-submit" disabled>Submit</button>`

After that check whether the user entered any input in input field or not. If input field is empty or contains only white spaces then

`$('#edit-submit').prop('disabled', true);`

else you can enable the button

`$('#edit-submit').prop('disabled', false);`

you can also use the `trim()` to remove white spaces

And also if you want to prevent the button disabled by default, you can check the input field value on page load using `$(document).ready(function () { // code to check the inpul field is empty or not on page load })`.